# Rotate ModelInstance Libgdx

Tags: android, 3d, rotation, libgdx, axis

I want to create sphere moving with rolling by velocity of sphere.
Unfortunately I noticed that when I change the rotation of modelinstance It also rotate axisX. So when I rotate in axisX then rotation of axisY (for example) doesn't work rightly.

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)){
                    marbles[3].transform.rotate(-1, 0, 0, 3);
                }
                if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)){
                    marbles[3].transform.rotate(1, 0, 0, 3);
                }
                if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)){
                    marbles[3].transform.rotate(0, 0, 1, 3);
                }
                if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)){
                    marbles[3].transform.rotate(0, 0, -1, 3);
}
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/xoppa/3b841fb52f46e8cdec24

Comment: Thank you. I dont understand this lines of code: tmpQ.set(tmpV.set(velocity).scl(-1f/speed).crs(Vector3.Y), speed*delta*MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
rotation.mulLeft(tmpQ);